# BoneCP Enterprise Use & General Stability

Tags: bonecp

We would like to use BoneCP in our application but as part of the assesment process I need to answer the following questions

Are there known examples of BoneCP being deployed on enterprise scale projects. How has it performed ?

The current release is 0.7 dose this indicate that it is a beta release. How long has BoneCP been in development ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'm using 0.7.1.RELEASE in a large enterprise (finance) in multithreaded batches. I tried Atomikos, DBCP and C3P0, all gave me deadlocks or performance problems. BoneCP works like a charm, and is lightning fast!